# Is it possible to call knitr::spin on two different R scripts and produce a single html file?

Tags: r, knitr, knitr-spin

I have two different R scripts. I love the idea of knitr::spin. I wanted to know if there's a way to call spin on these two scripts which are both formatted with roxygen2 and produce a single report.

Comment: You can source() with results='asis' option. See https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/621. Would this be what you want?

Comment: `source` will only print results if you use the `print` function, if not they will be "hidden". Also `source` will not render the `rocygen2` text. You can use `spin_child` which is mentioned in the same link KenM indicated, But the `spin_child` line appears also in the report which is a bit annoying.

Comment: > Also source will not render the rocygen2 text.

Totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `text` parameter in the `spin` function. Use `readLines` to read the files and then `cat` to write the output:

```
cat (spin (text = c (readLines ("file_one.r"),
                     readLines ("file_two.r"))),
     file = "output.html")
```

Comment: Ah! Nice and simple solution. Thanks!